# ModuleNotFound error while running pytest in Github actions

Tags: python-3.x, github, github-actions

I have a Python package and I setup Github actions for it using Python package (without conda) template. And I keep getting errors for dependencies I have in the package although I install them in yaml.

```
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "stage"]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "stage"]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7"]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest black
        pip install toml && python -c 'import toml; c = toml.load("pyproject.toml"); print("\n".join(c["build-system"]["requires"]))' | pip download -r /dev/stdin  --dest=dest 
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        python -m black src
        python -m black tests
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        python -m pytest .
```

And the errors I get for several dependencies like

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/my_package/tests/test_helpers.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_helpers.py:2: in <module>
    from spacy import tokens
```

And this error occurs not only with spacy but also with bs4 although i have them both in the list of dependencies in pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=61.0",
    "wheel",
    "numpy==1.21.6",
    "beautifulsoup4~=4.12.2",
    "spacy==3.4.4",
    "pytest==7.3.1",
    "pytest-env==0.8.1"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I already tried to downgrade pytest, changed how I install requirements and order of steps in the yaml itself. I don't understand what else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be about your dependencies missing spacy

Install your package's dependencies in the GitHub Actions workflow and
Install your package itself in "editable" mode. This will make sure that when the tests run, they have access to the package and its dependencies.

Updated Workflow: I am adding a requirements.txt file, Assuming you have a requirements.txt. Otherwise, install necessary packages explicitly.

```yaml
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master", "stage"]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master", "stage"]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.7"]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest black
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Install package in editable mode
      run: |
        pip install -e .
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        python -m black src
        python -m black tests
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        python -m pytest .
```

Comment: With spacy it's only as an example cos I have errors with a few other packages too all of which are included in the requirements